# How do I make my recursive algorithm to stop once the target is reached?

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search

I am trying to solve a problem for the following question.

`Find path for a robot in a maze from top left corner to bottom right corner.
The robot can move only to the right or bottom.
There are certain restricted areas where the robot cannot go into.`

My idea is to use depth first search going right first and then going bottom.
My algorithm is working.
But I have gotten quite rusty with recursion. I am not able to return the output properly.
This is my code

```
def robot_path(r, c, off_limits):
    """
    r -> number of rows in grid
    c -> number of columns in grid
    off_limits -> nested list containing positions of restricted areas
    """
    grid = list()
    for i in range(0, r):
        grid.append([1] * c)
    for off_limit in off_limits:
        grid[off_limit[0]][off_limit[1]] = 'X'
    path = list()
    return __move(grid, (0,0), path, (r-1, c-1))

def __move(grid, position, path, target):
    if position == target:
        return path
    x = position[0]
    y = position[1]
    if x < len(grid) and y < len(grid[0]):
        if grid[x][y] != 'X':
            path.append(1)
            __move(grid, (x, y+1), path, target)
            path.pop()
            path.append(0)
            __move(grid, (x+1, y), path, target)
            path.pop()
```

How can I return the path?
In the `path` list, `0` means moving bottom and `1` means moving right. However, my algorithm does not stop once it reaches the bottom right. It runs even after that and I’m getting a None output. How do i change this to return my path once the bottom right is reached.

**Test output**

`robot_path(4, 4, [[0,2], [2,2], [3,0], [3, 1]])`

should return

`[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

Without simply giving the answer, I would suggest thinking about the following

- The second function doesn't have a `return` in all paths, only in the first `if`
- Recursive functions are usually not combined with mutable objects. Your path object is mutated using `pop()`. Usually in recursive functions it is clearer if objects are only passed and returned, not mutated inline

eg:

```
def sum(l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return 0
    return l[0] + sum(l[1:])
```

The tail is passed down to the next function, the result is passed back up the chain. The list itself is not mutated within the `sum()` function, just broken into pieces for the purpose of passing down.

Comment: I got it to work by adding parameter called paths and when the target is reached, it adds a copy of the path to the paths list. But how do I do this without it. I am quite confused. I mean I dont wan't it to keep searching for other paths too. Once a path is found it has to return it all the way up but there are two recursive calls in the else block. Any more tips?

Comment: Depending on how you construct it, it may not be a problem to pass a variable called paths back up. In some versions you may just be able to work with return values as in the simpler `sum()` example. You just want to make sure that every time you make a recursive call, you give a separate part of the search space to the new invocation. Just as in the `sum()` call you give a new part of the list to analyse to the call one further down.